# Devise: after successful login hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my rails app, I am using devise for my authentication system. I have a situation in which I want to encrypt some data using a key that is based off of the user's password. The easiest way that I can think to do this is during a successful sign in, to generate the user's private key from their plain-text password (passed in from the login form) and store that in the user's session. I don't really want to ask the user to enter their password more than once.

Does devise provide a way to specify a callback function after a successful login? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#after_database_authentication-instance_method

In the user model where you're using devise create a after_database_authentication instance method.

Comment: Does that method have access to the plain-text password?

Comment: Same question as above, are the plain text passwords available through this method?

Comment: @jasonfunk For reference, the only way to get access to the plain text password is to grab it from `resource_params` or similar before you create the user record. Once record is stored and they are logged in there is no way to retrieve the plain text version. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795120/displaying-user-password-with-devise-confirmation-page

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have Devise resourse `User` with attribut `password`, then you can access user password after login in `after_sign_in_path_for`, which is called after sucessful login.

```
  # app/control,lers/application_controller.rb
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      password = param[:user][:password]
      do_cool_stuf_with_password(password)
      #... 
      return url_for_root
   end
end
```