# Displaying User Password With Devise Confirmation Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm attempting to display a users password along in his confirmation page sent by the Devise mailer. The confirmation page is the default

```
Welcome test0@test.com!

You can confirm your account email through the link below:

Confirm my account
```

However, I wish to have

```
Welcome test0@test.com!

Your password is currently DASADSADS

You can confirm your account email through the link below:

Confirm my account
```

How do I access the user object in the view? Do I need to override the mailer controller with a custom one? If so, how do I tell what the methods of the current mailer do (tried looking at documentation but can't find any clues)?

I noticed that @email and @resource are used in the view. Can I use any of these to access the current password in its unhashed form?

Note that I am sending this email manually with `user.find(1).send_confirmation_instructions`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3w3XvGU.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this can be done, I would caution *very strongly* against doing so.  Hashed passwords are specifically used so that the password cannot be recreated easily.  Passing the original password back to the user will cause it to be sent back in plain text which sort of defeats the whole purpose.  Also, shouldn't the user already know their password (they did type it in twice after all)?!?

To do this, you would need to capture the original (unhashed) password in the registration `create` action and send the email at that point (passing along the password).  You can do this by overriding the `sign_up` method - you can do this in an initializer:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    resource.unhashed_password = resource_params[:password]
    resource.send_confirmation_instructions
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can derive a new controller from `Devise::RegistrationsController` and put this override code there (the recommended approach - but then again, this whole operation isn't really recommended).  You'll need to add the `unhashed_password` accessor for this to work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :unhashed_password
end
```

And then you can update your confirmation view (at `app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb`) to contain this:

```
<p>Your password is currently <%= @resource.unhashed_password %></p>
```

Comment: Thank you this response is what I was looking for. However, my situation is slightly different ( I should have elaborated ). The user has already been created with User.new(...) in the same controller that calls user.find(1).send_confirmation_instructions. So, I have the unhashed password in that view is there anyway I can pass this into the resource object from a custom controller?

Comment: @user1431282: After leaving the `create` action, the browser is sent a redirect to another path.  Once this happens, it is impossible to recapture the unhashed password, as it is not stored anywhere and cannot be reverse engineered.  As such, the only place in the workflow that this can be done is in the same action that actually sets the password (and has access to the unhashed version) which occurs as part of the `create` action.

Answer (score 1):

Devise save password in encrypted form: You can decrypt it using,

Generate new migration:

```
$ rails g migration AddLegacyPasswordToUser legacy_password:boolean
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20120508083355_add_legacy_password_to_users.rb
$ rake db:migrate
```

Using legacy_password method in following code you can decrypt your password:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

...

  def valid_password?(password)
    if self.legacy_password?
      # Use Devise's secure_compare to avoid timing attacks
      if Devise.secure_compare(self.encrypted_password, User.legacy_password(password))

        self.password = password
        self.password_confirmation = password
        self.legacy_password = false
        self.save!

      else
        return false
      end
    end

    super(password)
  end

  # Put your legacy password hashing method here
  def self.legacy_password(password)
    return Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{password}-salty-herring");
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use request.request_parameters[:user][:password] to get the plain text password on the create or update action.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer